# Is it a valid operation to cast a void* pointer to char* pointer and doing pointer arithmetics on it?

Tags: c, arrays, list, pointers

I have a Pointer(void*) to a malloc'ed block/array in memory, and I know the Size of the data structure that is stored in that block. I want to be able to iterate over the block to get access to any single value.

Program knows:

- that void* Pointer will point to the start of this malloc'ed block of memory.
- the  Size[in bytes] of each value, but not the data structure that is actually stored.
- the  Capacity[in bytes]: potential amount of those values(how much memory is allocated)

This means that I have  malloc'ed: Capacity*Size_of_value bytes, and I want to get a pointer to any value that is inside that block, by:

1. Casting the void* Pointer into char* Pointer.
2. Adding a required multiple of Size_of_value to the char*Pointer: thus getting a pointer to any required value.

What I learned, is that adding N to a char* pointer, causes it to move forward by N bytes. And as I know that the pointer has to be moved forward by [amount] of bytes, I can add [amount] to this char* pointer.

I couldn't find a proper source for this, and generally only found out for sure that arithmetics on a void* isn't allowed.

From what I hacked together so far, it seems to work properly, as long as the stored structure has a constant, known size. A flexible array member in the struct breaks my current implementation. This is a shortcoming that I'm planning to fix by creating an extension: the list will hold a pointer to an array of pointers, and those pointers will give access to the actual values.

---

Context that might or might not be useful:

I am working on an implementation of a list data structure, and I implemented it as basically a dynamic array(expanding and shrinking whenever needed) with more interface.

I know about linked lists, and I'm also planning to implement them as a different exercise.

I defined the list like this:

```
typedef struct TLIST_
{
    size_t size_of_value;      // size [in bytes] of each record stored in the list
    size_t list_capacity;      // memory has been allocated for this many values(size can't be larger than this)

    size_t list_size;          // number of stored records 
    void* pointer_to_zero;     // address of the content
} tlist;

// The list has a few other values for various options and operations(e.g.: disallowing it to expand automatically, displaying the content), but those four values is all that's needed for this problem.
```

The function for getting a pointer to a value at given index:

```
void* tehlist_generic_getPointerToIndex(const tlist* list__, const int index__) 
{
    const int capacity =  (*list__).list_capacity;
    if( index__ >= 0 && index__ < capacity )
    {
        // Move pointer forward by a given amount of bytes, through casting the void* to a char*
        // 1. Can't do pointer arithmetic on void*, but can on char*
        // 2. char* is defined as 1[unit or byte],
        // thus moving char* forward by N, causes it to move as if we were moving through a pointer that was of size N

        void* pointer_to_index = (*list__).pointer_to_zero;

        const size_t bytes_forward = (*list__).size_of_value*index__;
        pointer_to_index = (char*)(pointer_to_index) + ( bytes_forward );

        return pointer_to_index;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Additional information I found:

GNU C compiler offers a C language extensions that allows arithmetic on `void*`, by treating it as if it had size of 1 (like it was casted into `char*`):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

This isn't allowed in ISO C, only in GNU C.

Comment: Yes.  Unless you're using GCC (or a compiler emulating GCC), you cannot do arithmetic directly on a `void *`.  So, you must convert to a pointer to some other type, and `char *` is often the best alternative, but it does depend on context.

Comment: Note the restrictions on structures containing a FAM (flexible array member): [C11 §6.7.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3) Structure and union specifiers: ¶3 _A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (…), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
element of an array._

Comment: Thank you for the comment, though I'd like to ask for clarification I don't understand this sentence: "such structure[incomplete type, like the flexible array member] shall not be a member of a structure". Does that mean, the FAM isn't a part of the structure, but rather the structure only holds a reference to this object? Thus the size of struct would be constant, no matter the FAM's size.

I'm actually using what I believe is GCC(mingw-gcc), and I indeed noticed that it's due to the [-Wpointer-arith] option.(for fellow novices: enable all compilers warnings, it will save you many times).

Comment: The size of a structure with a FAM does not include the size of the FAM (but the size of the structure may be bigger than it would be without the FAM; for example `struct fam1 { char c; double fam[]; };` probably has size 8 (maybe 4 on 32-bit Intel), but without the FAM would have size 1).  The array goes directly after the fixed portion of the structure, which is why you can't have them in an array — the elements of an array are a fixed distance apart, so if it were not for the prohibition, you'd only be able to have an array of struct-with-FAM where every FAM was empty, which is pointless.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. Though can I force the program to check whether the structure contains a flexible array member? My implementation doesn't have any way to know about the structure itself: only the size is passed to the list's function, and I can't think of any way to add such knowledge without breaking the simple universality of storable structures. On the other hand though, my implementation is supposed to be hidden by a layer of abstraction anyway. Maybe I'm thinking about too many things.

Comment: You can’t tell whether a structure has a FAM in it programmatically, any more than you can identify the non-FAM members.  You can have arrays of pointers to individually allocated structures with FAM elements.

Comment: The code as posted appears to assume a `struct TLIST_` can be aligned at any memory address.  Trying that on hardware with strict alignment restrictions on data types can and will result in something like `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS`.

Comment: Andrew: what do you mean? I don't see how it would be a problem: A tlist is initialized by #A: 1. "tlist* list malloc(sizeof(tlist));" 2. "void initializeTlistInPlace(tlistl* tlist, parameters);  "(which inputs the required information into the given address) #B 1. variable "tlist var_tlist;" 2.  use function "tlist createTlist(parameters)" which returns a tlist. Thus, the tlist's address in memory is decided by the operating system: either as a variable or address that was prepared with malloc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, casting to char * is always legal, dereferencing that pointer is only legal within the bounds of the allocated block.

Answer (score 1):

The C99 standard says in 6.3.2.3:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type
>   may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.

So yes it is perfectly valid as long as you do the arithmetic with the pointer of the actual type(in this case char*).

Comment: *A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again* This isn't applicable to this question.  Your quoted section refers to a pointer starting as `void *`, being converted to another type, then returned to `void *`, with no other changes.  There's no mention of modifying the value of the intermediate pointer, hence the *the result shall compare equal to the original pointer* portion.